# cordova printer plugin is not printing t

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, printers

I m trying to print a html file from my cordova app.
I have installed the cordova-plugin-printer.
In app.module.ts file imported the plugin and after that when i try to use this.printer.print('hello')
Noting happens at all

import { Printer, PrintOptions } from '@ionic-native/printer/ngx';

private printer: Printer

```
Print(){
  console.log("Print Pressed");
  var options = {
    font: {
        size: 22,
        italic: true,
        align: 'center'
    },
    header: {
        height: '6cm',
        label: {
            text: "\n\nDie Freuden",
            font: {
                bold: true,
                size: 37,
                align: 'center'
            }
        }
    },
    footer: {
        height: '4cm',
        label: {
            text: 'Johann Wolfgang von Goethe, 1749-1832, deutscher Dichter, Naturforscher',
            font: { align: 'center' }
        }
    }
};

this.printer.print("hello",options);
  console.log("Print Pressed>>>");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Print(){
let options: PrintOptions = {
     name: 'MyDocument',
     printerId: 'printer007',
     duplex: true,
     landscape: true,
     grayscale: true
};
//Checks whether the device is capable of printing
this.printer.isAvailable().then(()=>{
   console.log("printer available")
}).catch((error)=>{
   console.log("printer not available"+error); 
}); 
}
```

Comment: the code does not get executed, neither goes to success nor failure. I have written a console log just after the Print() , only that gets printed in the console.

Comment: that mean not printer available

Comment: No printer is connected, i m trying on simulator right now, but it should atleast show the print preview page

Comment: oh so you want to see preview.

Comment: Nothing is working at all, neither can i see the preview nor any console statement , right now i m running the code on ios simulator and does not have any connected printer